# How to convert EMG data of type 'list' to vector or data frame when unlist and as.data.frame don't work?

Tags: r

[image] 
I have a really long list of EMG data that I need to convert to a vector or data frame before using the biosignal EMG package in R. It doesn't work with lists. The EMG data is .csv and is in the form shown in the picture.
I tried using the as.data.frame function, but it still gave me a list. 
I also tried unlisting it, but it gave me an integer instead. 
There are 2 columns and 647 rows. 
I need to plot the data in the 2nd column and starting from row 8 till row 647. 
How do I do this?

Below is the code I used:

```
library(biosignalEMG) # ReadCSV
MyEMGdata151517 <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\zyous\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AsciiTraceDump_190211_151517.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
MyEMGdata151543<-read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\zyous\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AsciiTraceDump_190211_151743.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
Rectified_EMG_151517<-rectification(MyEMGdata151517,rtype = "fullwave")
M<-as.data.frame.array(MyEMGdata151543) is.data.frame(M) #Rectifying 151517
Rectified_EMG_151517 <- rectification(MyEMGdata151517, rtype = "fullwave")
Rectified_plot_151517<-plot(MyEMGdata151517, main = "Rectified EMG")
```

When I try to rectify, I get this error: Error in rectification(MyEMGdata151517, rtype = "fullwave") : an object of class 'emg' is required.
 And that error I think is because my file is not a vector. But how do i convert it when unlist wont work I wanna see peaks like the kind you would get in excel doing this.

Comment: how are you reading the CSV file into R? Can you please post some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: library(biosignalEMG)
# ReadCSV 
MyEMGdata151517 <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\zyous\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AsciiTraceDump_190211_151517.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
MyEMGdata151543<-read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\zyous\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AsciiTraceDump_190211_151743.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")


Rectified_EMG_151517<-rectification(MyEMGdata151517,rtype = "fullwave")
M<-as.data.frame.array(MyEMGdata151543)
is.data.frame(M)

#Rectifying 151517
Rectified_EMG_151517 <- rectification(MyEMGdata151517, rtype = "fullwave")
Rectified_plot_151517<-plot(MyEMGdata151517, main = "Rectified EMG")

Comment: When I try to rectify, I get this error: Error in rectification(MyEMGdata151517, rtype = "fullwave") : an object of class 'emg' is required

And that error I think is because my file is not a vector. But how do i convert it when unlist wont work

I wanna see peaks like the kind you would get in excel doing this.

Comment: ok, this is helpful! Can you please edit your original question with the code instead of adding it as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are not converting the variable created with `read.csv()` into an `emg` object. The documentation gives the following example:

```
x <- rnorm(10000, 0, 1)
emg1 <- emg(x, samplingrate=1000, units="mV", data.name="")
summary(emg1)
EMG Object
    Total number of samples: 10000
    Number of channels: 1
    Duration (seconds):  10
    Samplingrate (Hertz):  1000
    Channel information:
    Units:  mV
plot(emg1, main="Simulated EMG")
```

Which yields:
[image]

Based on the attached image in your question I think you should do something similar with `emg2 <- emg(MyEMGdata151517$X8, samplingrate=1000, units="mV", data.name="")`